# For string, strip away the numbers that come after letters

Tags: postgresql

Given a string, strip away the numbers that come after letters. If the inputs look like the left column below, I want the outputs to look like the right column.

| inputs | outputs |
| --- | --- |
| 415-424-4005 XT. 21 | 415-424-4005 XT. |
| 1-800-552-3319 EXT 2606 | 1-800-552-3319 EXT |
| 713-840-9300 X104 | 713-840-9300 X |
| 800-454-1628 OPTION#1 | 800-454-1628 OPTION# |
| +1 (844) SAVE-529 | +1 (844) SAVE- |
| 424-252-4813 (EXT 5013) | 424-252-4813 (EXT ) |
| 1-800-55OAKWELL | 1-800-55OAKWELL |
| +1 (212) 603-2800 (EST) | +1 (212) 603-2800 (EST) |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the input strings into parts with `regexp_match()` (used in a lateral join) and remove digits from the second part with `regexp_replace()`:

```sql
select input, concat(part[1], regexp_replace(part[2], '\d', '', 'g')) as output
from the_data
cross join regexp_match(input, '(.+[A-Z]+)(.*)') as part
```

In more complex queries a custom function can be very useful. Define the function once and use it in various contexts:

```sql
create function remove_digits_after_letters(input text)
returns text language sql immutable as $$
    select concat(part[1], regexp_replace(part[2], '\d', '', 'g'))
    from regexp_match(input, '(.+[A-Z]+)(.*)') as part
$$;

select remove_digits_after_letters('415-424-4005 XT. 21')
```

Test it in [Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=86041568612dcdfb6b6c61ebe9b3a10a)

Read about the functions in [the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)

Comment: Wonderful solution. It certainly worked. Thanks.